# Astropy Package - Defining new dark energy parametrization

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, computational-physics, software

I was looking through [astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.cosmology.w0waCDM.html#astropy.cosmology.w0waCDM), and I wonder is it possible to define a new dark energy parametrization instead of using the [pre-defined](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/cosmology/index.html#classes) ones..? I couldn't see the reference but maybe I missed it.

Thanks

Edit:
I need to change the internal logic. Main main logic is to define a new dark energy with parameters $\lambda, \gamma$, such that $\rho_{\rm DE} \equiv \rho_{\rm DE}(\gamma, \lambda) = \rho_{\rm DE,0}\Gamma(z)$. Where $\Gamma(z)$ is a some function of redshift.

In the given models by astropy, the DE model parameters (and naturally the $\Gamma(z)$) is pre-defined. I need to define a new   $\rho_{\rm DE}(z)$ with my own (number of) parameters and $\Gamma(z)$. (It's same as defining a new $w_{\rm DE}$).

For instance this [model](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.cosmology.w0waCDM.html#astropy.cosmology.w0waCDM) defines the $w_{\rm DE}$ as

$$w_{\rm DE} \equiv w_{\rm DE}(w_0, w_a) = w_0 + w_az/(1+z)$$

Meanwhile, I want to define new $w_{\rm DE}$, with a new parameters and with a new function.

Edit 2: I saw this in the docs

> Users can specify their own equation of state by subclassing FLRW. See the provided subclasses for examples. It is advisable to stick to subclassing FLRW rather than one of its subclasses, since some of them use internal optimizations that also need to be propagated to any subclasses. Users wishing to use similar tricks (which can make distance calculations much faster) should consult the cosmology module source code for details.

I'll look more but I am also still looking for an answer..

It seems there's a way...but still searching. It seems a bit tricky

Comment: If you click each class, you'll see the parameters that can be set on them; even those with a default value can be given a value of your choice. You can also write new classes inheriting from an existing class to change the internal logic. If you edit your question to say _what_ change you need, someone can probably help you with the code.

Comment: I edited my question. I dont think someone can help me with the code...maybe I can try to do it myself...Do you think it would be possible to create a new class by using the existing ones ?

Comment: If it is possible to create a new model, I am sure someone must have done it right..Maybe I can also look at it.. but I guess there cannot be any way to look at it... I guess first I need to look how $w_{\rm DE}$ is defined in astropy and change the code.

Comment: I've posted something that might help you experiment with creating a subclass. If you try it but can't get it to behave as expected, that's probably best remedied by googling whatever the problem is, then asking at Stack Overflow if you need to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment; but construed as an answer, this may need to evolve if the question is updated. For now, it can't give a precise solution, but is intended to guide the OP experimenting. Hopefully this question will be moved to a more coding-friendly site, where this comment cum answer will be appropriate.

You linked to the source code for `w0waCDM`, a subclass of `FLRW`. You've also quoted documentation that advises creating such a subclass. It must override `FLRW`'s abstract method `w`; other overrides are optional.

Cutting some comments, docstrings and whitespace, and adding some new comments, imports and whitespace to advise you on how to do something similar, that class looks like this:

```
from astropy.cosmology.flrw.base import FLRW
from astropy.modeling import Parameter

class w0waCDM(FLRW):#You'll want to change the name outside the brackets

    #Attributes listed here, created using Parameter, also have underscored counterparts registered as explained at
    #https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.Parameter.html
    w0 = Parameter(doc="Dark energy equation of state at z=0.", fvalidate="float")
    wa = Parameter(doc="Negative derivative of dark energy equation of state w.r.t. a.", fvalidate="float")
    #As shown here, a number of attributes already get a similar treatment:
    #https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/cosmology/flrw/base.html#FLRW

    #Advice hereafter assumes you don't change any functions' argument lists, but you can
    def __init__(self, H0, Om0, Ode0, w0=-1.0, wa=0.0, Tcmb0=0.0*u.K, Neff=3.04, m_nu=0.0*u.eV, Ob0=None, *, name=None, meta=None):
        # If you override __init__, start the new logic with the line below
        super().__init__(H0=H0, Om0=Om0, Ode0=Ode0, Tcmb0=Tcmb0, Neff=Neff, m_nu=m_nu, Ob0=Ob0, name=name, meta=meta)

        #Lines like these for the Parameter-based attributes
        self.w0 = w0
        self.wa = wa
        
        #__init__ method concludes with these lines; your needs may be different
        if self._Tcmb0.value == 0:
            self._inv_efunc_scalar = scalar_inv_efuncs.w0wacdm_inv_efunc_norel
            self._inv_efunc_scalar_args = (self._Om0, self._Ode0, self._Ok0, self._w0, self._wa)
        elif not self._massivenu:
            self._inv_efunc_scalar = scalar_inv_efuncs.w0wacdm_inv_efunc_nomnu
            self._inv_efunc_scalar_args = (self._Om0, self._Ode0, self._Ok0, self._Ogamma0 + self._Onu0, self._w0, self._wa)
        else:
            self._inv_efunc_scalar = scalar_inv_efuncs.w0wacdm_inv_efunc
            self._inv_efunc_scalar_args = (self._Om0, self._Ode0, self._Ok0, self._Ogamma0, self._neff_per_nu, self._nmasslessnu, self._nu_y_list, self._w0, self._wa)

    # Aforementioned compulsory method override; note the attribute names need _s
    def w(self, z): return self._w0 + self._wa * z / (z + 1.0)

    # Only other method the class changed; w might be all you need to change, but if you also need to change something else this is an example of how it's done
    def de_density_scale(self, z):
        z = aszarr(z)
        zp1 = z + 1.0
        return zp1 ** (3 * (1 + self._w0 + self._wa)) * exp(-3 * self._wa * z / zp1)
```

Hopefully, that illustrates to you how it's done. I recommend you look at the source code of other subclasses, and in particular for whatever follows `def w` in each of them, to see if any behave the way you want. (Also, if you still don't have the hang of subclassing, looking at existing classes will hopefully remedy that.)

Comment: I guess it will be a long journey but I guess I can manage to do it...I am not sure tho. It's also strange that there's not much info. I have also find this site https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/cosmology/dev.html . If I give you the $w_{\rm DE}$, and even you would write the code I am not sure that would help me much to understand the logic behind it... I guess the best I can do this compare LCDM and wCDM or w0waCDM (as you have said) and change stuff...